# YTD measure calculated separately for each month

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a measure calculated in the context of a selected month defined as:

```
MyMetric = COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( Entities, [Incident Count] > [Target] ) )
```

I need to calculate the YTD number while calculating each month separately. This is because a single Entity that exceeds the Target in two months needs to be counted twice, whereas a simple YTD calculation would only include it once. For example, when reporting March, a correct result is achieved with:

```
[MyMetric YTD] = [MyMetric]
                 + CALCULATE ([MyMetric] , DATEADD(DateTable[Date], -1 , MONTH))
                 + CALCULATE ([MyMetric] , DATEADD(DateTable[Date], -2 , MONTH))
```

Obviously, this is not the right way to do it. How can this kind of calculation be written efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that you have a `Month` column in your `DateTable`. If not, then you can create one.

Then you can try something along these lines:

```
MyMetric YTD
= SUMX(
      CALCULATETABLE(
          VALUES( DateTable[Month] ),
          DATESYTD( DateTable[Date] )
      ),
      [MyMetric]
  )
```

Basically, you get a list of each month in the year so far and then sum your measure value for each one of those months.

Comment: Thanks, it looked promising, but unfortunately, this returns the same result as [MyMetric] on its own

Comment: Nevermind, my DateTable[Month] was `= MONTH ( [Date] )` instead of `= EOMONTH ( [Date], 0 )`. The latter works perfectly. Thanks!!